# Convert String obtained from edittext to Integer in Kotlin language

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to make a simple Android application using Kotlin language.
I have one EditText, I am getting its value in String but I want to convert that value into an integer.
How can I convert this string to integer in **Kotlin language**?.

Comment: Google it. https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [`.toInt()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int.html):

```
val myNumber: Int = "25".toInt()
```

Note that it throws a `NumberFormatException` if the content of the String is not a valid integer.

If you don't like this behavior, you can use [`.toIntOrNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int-or-null.html) instead (since Kotlin 1.1):

```
val myNumOrNull: Int? = "25".toIntOrNull()
```

Answer (score 30):

The above is the general idea but here is a syntax straight out of Android Studio, from a different tutorial I'm doing.

Note that the compiler was perfectly happy to do a cast of a cast.

```
var myNewInt: Int = myEditTextView.text.toString().toInt()
```

Answer (score 2):

the returned value of (edittext.text) in kotlin 
is a editable? value and at the first
you must convert that to string

edittext.text.toString().toInt()